# How to use Qt's connect with a boost::scoped_ptr<QWidget>

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I'm modifying an existing program. I have in the class .h file:

```
boost::scoped_ptr<QWidget> _widget;
```

I have in my .cpp file a method:

```
void FaceRecoWidget::createWidget()
{
    _widget.reset(new QDialog);
    QVBoxLayout* layout(new QVBoxLayout);

    // some stuff...

    // Now I want to add a 'Cancel' button. This I what I do:    
    QPushButton* cancel_button(new QPushButton("Cancel"));
    // but next line won't compile because _widget is not a 'const QObject*'
    connect(cancel_button, SIGNAL(clicked()), _widget, SLOT(reject()));

    layout->addWidget(cancel_button);
    _widget->setLayout(layout);
}
```

How do I get around this?

Comment: you don't need `scoped_ptr` if you set `this` as the parent: `_widget = new QDialog(this);`

Comment: Why are you mixing two memory ownership models? You're writing Qt, use the hierarchical ownership model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`connect` accepts pointers, so you should pass the raw pointer that is stored in `boost::scoped_ptr`:

```
connect(cancel_button, SIGNAL(clicked()), _widget.get(), SLOT(reject()));
```